# One exposed filter with different values in one view

Tags: 7, commerce, views

I've searched a lot for this one with no luck.
My problem is the following:

I have an exposed filter of brands (adidas, nike, etc). It is displayed as a block on the home page.
while entering the brand and click apply, it displays a page containing two content types mall and store.

the store content type contains a term reference field brand.
As for the mall content type, it contains entity reference stores with term reference field brand in them.

If i add a relationship in the views for the referenced entity and enable the relationship on the exposed filter field brand, it will display the mall content type only. if i remove the relationship it will display the store content type only.

How can I have one exposed filter block to display both the malls and the stores?

I appreciate any help given.

I'm using drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [views autocomplete filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters), add all fields you wish in the view, including the ones with a relationship (can be: contentypes, commerce products and commerce line itmes with propper relationships), then on add an exposed filter choose: **Global: Combine fields filter**, and on filter settings select all fields you wish to filter on, like the image below. This wokrs on D7 & D8. Enjoy.

[image]